# How to aggregate data by time series and create a square matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, dendrogram

I am trying to plot a dendrogram according to the time series. I should base it on 27x27 matrix (country names in columns) and am only allowed to use R standard package, dplyr and ggplot2 libraries. I used to aggregate the data by mean but it turned out the plot below wasn't done this way. I'm struggling to understand how I am supposed to obtain one value for each country another way.

I should obtain such plot:
[goal dendrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXCjf.png)

```
library("eurostat")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

d <- get_eurostat("prc_hicp_manr") %>%
  filter(coicop == "CP00")

d2 <- label_eurostat(d) %>%
  filter(time %in% as.Date("2000-02-01"):as.Date("2022-09-30"), 
         geo %in% c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Chechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary",
                    "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", 
                    "Spain", "Sweden"))

d3 <- d2[,c("geo","values")]
d3

#m <- matrix(?)

dist <- dist(m, method = "minkowski", p = 1.5)

d3_hclust  <- hclust(dist, method = "complete")
d3_dend <- as.dendrogram(d3_hclust)
plot(d3_dend)
```

Comment: It is not clear where you get 27 x 27. You selected 25 countries and a block of time that includes 272 months.

Comment: I selected 27 countries and it says in the assignment that I should base the dendrogram on this HICP index time series change over time.

Comment: Look at `length(unique(d2$geo))`. You specified 27 countries but you only got 25. You did not get Germany because its name in the data is "Germany (until 1990 former territory of the FRG)" and you did not get "Chechia" because it is spelled "Czechia" in the data. Once that is fixed you will need to pivot the data.

Comment: Thank you, I would have never noticed. I misunderstood the assignment at first. I'm supposed to create a vector for each country with its time series and based on that calculate the distance matrix (27x27).